# Inheritence of Generic Tree Classes

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance, tree, class-design

i created a generic tree class (in C++, but i think it does not matter). The Tree class has members of the generic class, saved as List. For example:

```
template <T> class Tree {
    public: List<T> childs;
}
```

Now i have a class A, which should be a tree consisting of elements of class A. Like:

```
class A : public Tree<A>...
```

That is working well. So my objects of class A have an attribute childs as List of objects of type A.

The problem is, that now i want to create a class B, which is a Tree of elements of B (like with class A above), but which also is inheriting class A. Like:

```
class B: public Tree<B>, public A...
```

And so the name clash of childs happens. What i wanted, was that the elements of the Tree should no longer be A, but now of type B. I think my way to do it is wrong in many ways and that is my problem

Is there a nice way to create this tree of Elements of type B?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: As an example: I have the class for the tree and i create a class for humans. For the family part of humans i want to use the tree (in this example every human only has 1 parent...). So every human is a tree, and the childs are other humans (the children of the human itself). Now i want another class, for example female. A female clearly is a human and also i can create female as a tree, but this tree should only contain other females! So in short i want:

```
class Human : public Tree<Human>
class Female : public Human, public Tree<Female>
```

I hope this example clearifies my intentions...

Comment: `class B: public Tree<B>, virtual public A` perhaps?

Comment: _"Tree should no longer be A, but now of type B."_ Then inheritance is not the answer; you couldn't use `B` in place of `A`, which inheritance requires.

Comment: Introduce an intermediary template class `C` (implementing the members which were in `A` and you want in both `A` and `B`) inheriting from `Tree<T>` (where `T` is the template parameter), make `A` inherit from `C<A>` and `B` from `C<B>`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo this is not required by inheritance, but recommended by Liskov's Substitution Principle.

Comment: @Quentin How would that apply in this case? The language won't let you pass in a `Tree<B>` in place of a `Tree<A>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think that would work. `A` is actually inherited by `B` only once. What he wants to do is to replace `Tree<A>` inherited by `A` by `Tree<B>` (which isn't possible as far as I know, unless `A` is itself a template class with its parameter `T` defaulted to `A` and inherits from `Tree<T>` instead), it's not a problem of a class inherited several times and only needed once.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo passing a `B` instead of an `A` would compile, so inheritance definitely lets it happen. However, as you said you can't *functionally* replace an `A` with a `B` (because of the "no longer"), and this is a violation of the LSP (which is a design guideline, not a hard language rule).

Comment: @Caninonos Yeah you're right.

Comment: In your revision you define `Human` as an object that can have any kind of `Human` as children. If you want to say that a `Female` is a `Human`, this implies that a `Female` can have any kind of `Human` as children. It is then contradictory for you to try to define a `Female` as an object that can only have `Female` as children. Your intentions seem clear enough to me, but you appear to be trying to do something fundamentally impossible. I would recommend revising your plan.

Answer (score 2):

If an `A` is a tree of `A`'s,
But a `B` is not a tree of `A`'s,
Then a `B` can't be an `A`. Why would it ?

Comment: Liskov's substitution principle finally meets common sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

This raises the usual question of [composition vs. inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

A tree **is** not a list of trees. A tree is a container of elements of a certain type.  A tree **has** elements.  So the elements should be in the tree by composition (member of your generic tree) not by inheritance.

If you want to see a brilliant container design, have a look at the standard library.  You have standard containers, but none of these requires elements  to inherit from the container

If you'd follow this orientation and best-practice,  you'll have `Tree<A>` and a `Tree<B>` and there'd absolutely no issue. With this architecture you 'd have full benefit of the [separation of concerns](http://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/).

By the way, in the multiple inheritance that you are considering, you would have 2 trees:  the tree inherited from `A`, and the tree inherited from 
`Tree<B>`.

**Edit:**

What I try to say, taking your edited example, is that a human may appear in a tree but is not himself a tree.  This may sound philosophic, but it's an important aspect for the class design :  **You should only use inheritance if the relationship between two classes means "is a"**.  If you don't respect this rule, you'll sooner or later encounter difficulty. In your example, sooner.

Now if you want at all cost follow this way, there could be a workaround:

```
template <T> class Tree {
    public: List<shared_ptr<T>> childs;  // use pointers
};
class A : public Tree<A>; 
class B : public A;
```

In this case element `A` stores pointers to its children (preferably `shared_ptr<>` over raw pointers).  And each of these pointers could point to an `A` or any of its derived classes. You can eventually control the accessible interface of B, to allow only to add B children if you want.

Comment: My problem is with the part of the inheritence of template classes. It is correct, what you say, but i think it does not answer my question. I edited my question above and tried to make my question more clear.

Comment: I've perfectly understood your intent.  I've edited my answer to give additional arguments and a workaround.

Comment: Actually, a tree _does_ contain other trees of the same type: the "children" of each node in the tree are themselves trees. OP's use of inheritance to try to get composition still doesn't work, of course.

Comment: @david I think there's a semantic subtility:  a tree means the whole data structure (the root node and all its children until the leaves).  What you are speaking of are the nodes.  The nodes are individual parts of a tree.  But I agree with you (I upvoted your answer): you could under certain cirumstances consider each node as defining its own tree (i.e. not if your data structure caches some tree atributes such as height, nulber of leaves at the tree level).  The only generalized statements that is true in every case is that forests are made of trees ;-).

Comment: @Christophe I think you are taking the "global" definition of "tree" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure) and I am taking the "local" definition. They are both legitimate; I would consider "local" to be a little more "pure", but in practice "purity" of a data structure isn't worth much. In my previous comment, therefore, I should have said "can contain" rather than "does contain". (Mixing metaphors, OP is still "barking up the wrong tree" in my opinion.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a template more like this:

```
template <typename T> class Tree {
    public: List<Tree<T> > children;
}
```

Now you don't have to make `A` inherit from `Tree<A>`
in order to make the recursive structure of your tree,
or have `B` inherit from `Tree<B>`.
You can define

```
class B : public A
```

and then

```
class TreeOfB : public Tree<B>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand where exactly you are trying to get, but multiple inheritance is in general not a very good practice (unless you are inheriting from abstract classes).

One possibility you be to use aggregation/composition instead of inheritance, and let Tree be a member of your classes.

Another possibility would be to let A be a template class an inherit from A< B>.